# Fetch images from a network drive in php

Tags: php, image, networking, drive

I have a network drive in my intranet with say IP: `128.233.1.15`, which has a shared folder images containing profile images of all the users. Now in my PHP code, I try to fetch individual images of the users dynamically on their successful login from the network drive by making the image path as

`$imgdir="file:\\\\128.233.1.15\\images\\".$userid.".jpg";`

And then I use this `$imgdir` in `<img src>`, but the required image is not fetched on the PHP page when a user logs in. 
But when I directly open the link  `file:\\\\128.233.1.15\\images\\".$userid.".jpg`  in the web browser, the required image is fetched, but it's not getting fetched by the PHP code.

I have also tried mapping of the network drive and other combinations of the `filepath`, but it still isn't working.

Comment: sounds like a permission issue

Comment: @rtfm, can u please elaborate the permission issue

Comment: a way is to install Apache on that computer and from that fetch the images.

Answer (score 0):

I think Map your folder as drive if you are on windows. Provide them proper permissions and try again with the drive path.

Comment: I also tried mapping the drive and it has the permissions also, as the images are accessible through the browser directly but still the images are not being fetched by the php code

Comment: Find your Php user. If you are on apache than it could be apache. Check their permissions specifically.